# Build Project with QtSerialPort

Tags: qt, makefile

I want to build a project wich is using QtSerialPort. I'm using Qt 5.2.1 and Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. So, I have not to download QtSerialPort (?) See the news from 2013-07-03 [here](http://wiki.qt.io/QtSerialPort#e290b0f84383a96ecdf7f6b720b72092).

I'm creating a Makefile with cmake, which works. If I execute make, I got this error:

fatal error: **private/qringbuffer_p.h**: No such file or directory.

I have no idea what I have to do. Maybe it is a problem between Qt4 and Qt5?

---

If I clone the mirror as described here under [Gettig the source code](http://wiki.qt.io/QtSerialPort#e290b0f84383a96ecdf7f6b720b72092) I can't execute the command

```
git checkout qt5.2.1
```